# Showing $(r+x)\,2^s \leq r\,2^{x+s}$, for $x,r \in \mathbb{N}$, $s \in \mathbb{Z}^-$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I need help proving the following inequality:

> Suppose that $x,r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s \in \mathbb{Z}^-$ I want to show that $$(r+x)\,2^s \leq r\,2^{x+s}$$

Notice that equality is achieved when $x = 0$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The parameter $s$ is irrelevant since can divide the inequality by $2^s$.

Comment: Suppose $r=1$. Then we're essentially trying to show that $x\le 2^x-1$ which does not hold for $x=1/2$ for instance, so the inequality does not hold in general.

Comment: Should $r$ be an integer? Otherwise it shouldn't hold if $s = -1, r = 0.1, x = 1$.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Jamāl, I want $x$ to be an integer. I will edit the post. Thank you!

Comment: The inequality clearly doesn’t hold if $x\to 0$, $r\to 0$.

Comment: @RobertMurray Thank you for the pointing out. I want r and x both integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ and $r$ are integer then:

$$r\cdot 2^x=r\cdot (1+1)^x\overset{Bernoulli}\ge r\cdot(1+1\cdot x)= r+rx \ge r+x.$$

Comment: Thank you a lot! I didn't knew about Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: Wait, does that hold for any integers $x$ and $r$ or are they required to be positive?

Comment: Well, you can see all the cases when the Bernoulli’s inequality works [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality). Clearly, if $r<0$, $x=-r$, the inequality $2^x\cdot r \ge x+r$ doesn’t hold.